# How to track shipment details in Excel without opening browser?

Tags: excel, vba

I have so many shipment details that I need to track and record the input in an Excel spreadsheet daily. Doing it manually is so hectic. For example, I have tracking IDs in column A of Sheet1 and would like to pull tracking data from column B onwards. The shipping line website is [www.msc.com](http://www.msc.com). Suppose, tracking IDs (BL number) are MEDUUG990010, MEDUUG990093, MEDUUG990119 and each shipment is carrying five containers. In that case, details of all the containers of each shipment will be reflected in the Excel file like the attached picture.[image]

I have tried below VBA but it is not working by saying Run time error 424: Object required.

```
Sub track_shipment()
Dim trackNum As String, IE As Object, table As MSHTML.HTMLTable, finalPODETA As String, row As Double, col As Double
trackNum = "MEDUUG931675"
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.navigate "https://www.msc.com"
IE.Visible = False
While IE.busy
    DoEvents
Wend
Call delay(2)
IE.document.getElementById("ctl00_ctl00_Header_TrackSearch_txtBolSearch_TextField").Value = trackNum
IE.document.getElementById("ctl00_ctl00_Header_TrackSearch_hlkSearch").Click
Call delay(2)
finalPODETA = IE.document.getElementById("ctl00_ctl00_plcMain_plcMain_rptBOL_ctl00_rptContainers_ctl01_pnlContainer").getElementsByClassName("containerStats singleRowTable table-equal-3")(0).getElementsByTagName("td")(2).textContent
finalPODETA = Trim(finalPODETA)
Set table = IE.document.getElementById("ctl00_ctl00_plcMain_plcMain_rptBOL_ctl00_rptContainers_ctl01_pnlContainer").getElementsByClassName("resultTable")(0)
For row = 0 To table.Rows.Length - 1
    For col = 0 To 4
        Sheet1.Cells(5 + row, col + 1).Value = table.Rows(row).Cells(col).innerText
    Next col
Next row
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") = finalPODETA
Exit Sub
```

End Sub
Function delay(seconds As Long)
Dim endTime As Date
endTime = DateAdd("s", seconds, Now())
Do While Now() < endTime
DoEvents
Loop
End Function

Is there any way to track and record the data in an Excel file without opening the browser using VBA?

Comment: https://developerportal.msc.com/api-details#api=DPO-DCSATrackAndTrace-API-V2&operation=GET-events

Comment: @Vasily I have limited knowledge of VBA. However, I tried with my little knowledge but it is not working.

Comment: "It is not working" does not help us to help you. What code did you try? What messages did you get? Etc Etc. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @CHill60 I have added the code in the post.

Comment: Internet Explorer is no longer available - you will need to use a 3rd party product such as  Selenium

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@S.Shotez you can use API of msc.com, you can test API response here:
https://developerportal.msc.com/api-details#api=DPO-DCSATrackAndTrace-API-V2&operation=GET-events

just insert tracking item MEDUUG990010 in user form and it will return you URL:
https://ovhweportalapim.azure-api.net/dpo/trackandtrace/v2.2/events?carrierBookingReference=MEDUUG990010

copy into browser or click on url above and you will see JSON that can be parsed using JsonCoverter, here the link: https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON/blob/master/JsonConverter.bas

you need do import `JsonConverter.bas` into your VBAProject, here example how to work with api response:

```
Function MscApiJsonOutput(url As String) As Object
    Dim mscService As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60 'you need to activate "Microsoft XM L, v6.0" in References
    With mscService
        .Open "Get", url, False
        .SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
        .Send ""
        '.Status ' you can chech status before parse, e.g. if .Status = "401" then ....
        Set MscApiJsonOutput = JsonConverter.ParseJson(.responseText)
    End With
End Function
```

and routine that will use function above:

```
Sub getDataFromMsc()

    Dim baseUrl As String
    baseUrl = "https://ovhweportalapim.azure-api.net/dpo/trackandtrace/v2.2/events?carrierBookingReference="
    Dim shipment As String
    Dim json As Object
    Dim item, key
    
    shipment = "MEDUUG990010"
    
    Set json = MscApiJsonOutput(baseUrl & shipment)

    'here you need to extract the data you required   
    For Each item In json
        For Each key In item
            On Error Resume Next
            Debug.Print key, " : ", item(key)
            If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                Debug.Print key, " : Array ... "
                Err.Clear
            End If
    Next key, item
    
End Sub
```

Also, you need to add "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" into References because `JsonConverter.bas` use Dictionary.

tested:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time. But unfortunately, I am getting a Compile error : User-Defined type is not defined while marking mscService As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60.

Comment: @S.Shotez you need to activate "Microsoft XM L, v6.0" in VBAProject - References

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I activated v3.0. Now it is running but cannot get any data.

Comment: @S.Shotez I can't tell you why you cannot get any data, I've posted .gif file to show you that solution is tested and works fine (current output goes to immediate window). Now you have a direction and example on how to get required result, so you can debug, use watches to review variables and objects, you can post url into browser to review JSON and so on.

Comment: Thanks for your time and support. It means a lot and I will make it functional. Thanks again.